# Использование строк-шаблонов

Tags: javascript, строки

Как использовать строку-шаблон и нижеприведенные данные, чтобы получить вот такой результат:

> “There are 4 people on the tooling team.
>   Their names are Jennie, Ronald, Martin, Anneli.
>   2 of them have a senior role.”

```
const teamName = "tooling";

    const people = [
    {name: "Jennie", role: "senior"},
    {name: "Ronald", role: "junior"},
    {name: "Martin", role: "senior"},
    {name: "Anneli", role: "junior"}];
    let message = YOUR_CODE_HERE;
    console.log(message);
```

Answer (score 4):

Инъекции данных в строку шаблон осуществляются с помощью js-выражений, завёрнутых в сигнатуру `${expression}`:

```js
const teamName = "tooling";
const people = [
  {name: "Jennie", role: "senior"},
  {name: "Ronald", role: "junior"},
  {name: "Martin", role: "senior"},
  {name: "Anneli", role: "junior"}
];

let message = `There are ${people.length} people on the ${teamName} team. Their names are ${people.map(p=>p.name).join(', ')}. ${people.filter(p=>p.role==='senior').length} of them have a senior role.”`;

console.log(message);
```